# Magento - option to manage existing categories wont load

Tags: magento

I'm sure there will be an answer to this somewhere but I just cant seem to find it on here.

I recently moved my magneto store from my localhost to the live server - everything has gone relatively smoothly so far but I have encountered a couple of problems:

1: When in the 'Manage Categories' section I can create new categories which appear in the left column after refreshing the page - however clicking on these existing categories to edit them will do nothing (I simply get a loading message after which nothing happens - it just remains on the 'New Root Category' tab as shown below).

[image]

2: A similar problem when editing existing CMS pages - I can edit the page and save the changes however nothing will take effect - the website doesn't update and when I go back into the edit option all of the changes I've made have been undone.

I've tried a couple of things (Reindexing, refreshing cache) but nothing has worked yet. Obviously something has gone wrong when moving from the local host but I cant work out what.

Would greatly appreciate any help with this problem.

EDIT: I"ve also tried creating a new product - it was working up until the point when I went to select a category - everything else works but clicking on the category tab does nothing.

Comment: Give details on what have you done with your site ? Moved from local machine to server, installed any new extension, changed core code etc. etc.

Comment: I've not installed any new plugins since moving the site - I simply moved the site following the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiWmZFxrZns On my local server I still have an almost identical copy of the site that is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of Magento transfers before.  These are the steps I take:

1. Copy Magento Files.
2. Copy Database.
3. Open `app/etc/local.xml` and update the database connection information.
4. In the database table `core_config_data`, change both values for `path` equal to `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to the correct site URLs
5. In the Magento root, delete all files under `/var/cache/` and /var/session/`
6. Change the owner of all the files to the correct web user using `CHOWN` in shell.

In your case, it may be an issue of URL Rewrites.  Try truncating your `core_url_rewrite` table and seeing it that solves the issue.

**EDIT**

He was receiving a 406 error message which was related to `mod_security` blocking the ajax requests.  Disabling `mod_security` fixed the issue.

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestions but I'm afraid none of that worked :( I may try redoing the process of moving the website to the live server.. but I'm not sure if that would be a waste of time? As I said it does work perfectly on the local server but I cant see where it would have gone wrong in the process of moving it... so if there is a problem then its still in the code of the backup copy I have.

Comment: It's probably nothing to do with the code itself.  It could be server setting or configuration issue.  Are you certain that the server you've moved it to fully supports Magento?  I would recommend creating a new database and trying to do a fresh database install and seeing if your issues persist.

Comment: Also Im not sure if its of any relevance but I've been making a number of changes and the only difference I've noticed so far is that the 'Please Wait' message pictured in my original post no longer stays on the screen - it just flickers and disappears. :s

Comment: I've tried removing the website and starting the process again but I'm having the same problem. :( It may be possible that I edited a core file early on in the development of the site (its my first go at using magento and I didn't know any better! haha) could this be a possible cause?

Comment: Just delete `app/etc/local.xml` and try reinstalling to a new database.  If the issue still persists, install Firebug for Firefox, open the Net tab in Firebug and see if the ajax call is timing out.

Comment: Hi, I've tried reinstalling the DB and edited the local.xml file but I'm still having the same issue (the records that I had created while using the site on the localhost are still showing up on the live server - so the site is able to retrieve data from the DB but not the admin panel) When I click on one of the category tabs firebug shows the following message `
POST http://*site url*/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/800e5845d3e474558c280a6dd9a474e9/id/13/?isAjax=true
406 Not Acceptable - 3081ms`

Comment: also regarding posting new data - I've noticed that I can create a new category which will show up when I refresh the admin panel - but obviously I cant edit it. So it seems like alax is working to send and retrieve info from the DB for some things but not others. :s

Comment: The 406 error could be related to possibly `mod_security` being enabled on your hosting account.  See if you can disable `mod_security` through your control panel, or contact your host.  They will have the exact logs explaining why the request was denied.  Also make sure that you change the owner to the correct user and set the correct permissions of all of your Magento files using `chown` and `chmod`.

Comment: Thank you - disabling the mod_security did the trick! Still having an issue with editing CMS pages but I'll start a separate thread for that. Thanks again, I really appreciate it!