# Magento - Can't edit categories anymore after deleting and adding categories programmatically

Tags: magento

I wanted to clear all test categories to start with a clean database. I removed all categories with the following piece of code

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')>load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

// 1 is default store_id
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore(1)->getRootCategoryId();

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$db_read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$categories = $db_read->fetchCol("SELECT entity_id FROM " . $resource->getTableName("catalog_category_entity") . " WHERE entity_id>1 ORDER BY entity_id DESC");
foreach ($categories as $category_id) {
    if ($category_id == $rootCategoryId)
        continue;

    try {
        Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id)->delete();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

It removed everything except the root category. Once this was done, I added the categories through the API, that went pretty well. Now here comes the problem: When i tried to edit one of the categories in the Magento Admin, he only shows the [form to create a new root category](https://db.tt/AKHTU8b1).

What could be the cause of this? I found [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499827/magento-option-to-manage-existing-categories-wont-load) on SO which looked similar, but the solution mentioned there (disabling mod_security) didn't do the job for me. So i guess there is something else going on. It's very well possible that i haven't removed the categories in a good way.

I am pretty sure it can't be the API because i have added categories before that way, and i was able to edit them in the admin afterwards.

Can't wait for your help.

Comment: in the screenshot no category seems to be selected. is there any error in the javascript console? and in the logs?

Comment: The baviour is the same in case a category is selected: https://db.tt/t1AmmBYz. There is no error in the javascript console. And nothing about it in the logs..

Comment: Try doing a full re-index, clear all caches, log out and back in and see if that cure's it. If you have flat database enabled then try disabling that as well. If no code changes and it was working and there are no errors then I can only think it must be index or cache related.